# Where should the erlang_ls.config go

Tags: erlang, coc.nvim, erlang-ls

I want to use coc.nvim and elrang_ls in vim8.2. There are some problems. It report missing an erlang_ls.config when I open a erlang file. But i have erlang_ls.config in project root.
[image]

the result of `CocCommand workspace.showOutput` show it read config from unexpected place [image]
Where is  correct position for erlang_ls.config?
Sorry for my poor English. Thanks.

> It is possible to customize the behaviour of the erlang_ls server via
> a configuration file, named erlang_ls.config. The erlang_ls.config
> file should be placed in the root directory of a given project to
> store the configuration for that project.

Answer (score 0):

According to the picture, the clue has already been given to you. In the `els_config.erl` file `consult_config` function, line 126. error type = 2.

I think the information is enough, you can find source code file and read it and find why?

Answer (score 0):

It is need create `erlang_ls.config` in `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\erlang_ls` and `erlang_ls.config` `erlang_ls.yaml` in the project root path. But I don't know why.

Comment: Research on this more and try to find the reason. Welcome to stackoverflow!